# Why `position:absolute;` destroy ` vertical-align:middle`?

Tags: html, css

The text `center` is located at the center of div such as below code show.

```css
.Absolute-Center { 
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100px;  
  height: 100px; 
  border:1px solid red; 
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  }
```

```html
<div class="Absolute-Center">
    <p>center</p>
</div>
```

Now to add a line `position:absolute;` in the css of `.Absolute-Center`.

```css
.Absolute-Center { 
  position:absolute;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100px;  
  height: 100px; 
  border:1px solid red; 
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  }
```

```html
<div class="Absolute-Center">
    <p>center</p>
</div>
```

The text `center` was not at the center of div now ,why `position:absolute;` can result in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`position: absolute` interrupts on `display: table / table-cell`, so you need to `centered` using `padding` / 50% line-height of that `element's` height.

Instead use the `flexbox` properly like below.

Use This:

```css
.Absolute-Center {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  height: 100px;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Absolute-Center">
    <p>center</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Giving `position: absolute` to `diplay:table-cell` will force it to be `display: block`, and `vertical-align: middle;` does not work with block elemets

**[More Info](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo)**

you can wrap `Absolute-Center`

```css
.wrap {
  position: absolute;
}
.Absolute-Center {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class=wrap>
  <div class="Absolute-Center">
    <p>center</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is like a theorem ,can you show some  reasoning process behind the word?

Comment: why position: absolute forces diplay:table-cell to display: block ?

Comment: This link may help you https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo

Answer (score 2):

You can use **CSS Flexbox**.

Have a look at the code below:

```css
.Absolute-Center { 
  position: absolute;
  display: flex; /* Flexbox Property */
  justify-content: center; /* Horizontal Centering */
  align-items: center; /* Vertical Centering */
  width: 100px;  
  height: 100px; 
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="Absolute-Center">
    <p>center</p>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!